# How do I notate alternating quickly between two notes an octave away from each other?

Tags: piano, composition, ornaments

I'm vaguely sure that an ornament exists for this but I'm not sure which one it is. I'm a music theory beginner, so pardon me if there's a simple answer. Basically, I want to alternate quickly between two notes an octave away from each other, but I'm not sure which ornament accomplishes this. It's like a trill except a farther distance apart. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're describing a **tremolo**. You can find good information on how to write it in the post [What is this music symbol and how do I play it?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/88305/70803)

Comment: For those wondering, you can set a tremolo across any desired interval.